# How to Evaluate and Visualize the Positivity Assumption for the ATT

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, treatment-effect

I am trying to formally evaluate and visualize the satisfaction of the positivity assumption when estimating the ATT using R and I am having a tricky time figuring out how to do so. As [Greifer and Stuart](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.10577) point out, the positivity assumption can be relaxed a bit for estimating the ATT because we would only need counterfactuals for the treated units. In their paper, along with others I have seen, positivity can be visually assessed with density plots overlaying the density of treated and non-treated units for some X variable.

If we have several variables, what can be done to evaluate the distribution of treatment across a combination of covariates? Can the propensity score be used for these purposes? If so, is the solution as simple as:

1. Estimate propensity scores
2. Create a density plot of propensity scores for treated units
3. Overlay density plot of propensity scores for non-treated units
4. For ATT, check the degree to which the two density plots overlap

Answer (score 1):

For estimating the ATT, overlap means that the control gorup "encloses" the treated group; that is, the support of the treated group is in the support of the control group. The relaxedness of this requirement is that the control group doesn't need to be entirely in the support of the treated group; there can be control units that are vastly different from any treated units; they simply will be down-weighted or unmatched.

There is no universal way to assess overlap. For individual variables (including the propensity score), you can ensure that the range of the variable in the treated gorup is within the range of the variable in the control group. Ideally this "range" is not just the largest and smallest point, which may be outliers, but rather the range of the part of the distribution that contains enough data to make useful inferences without interpolating. One way to do this is to create a histogram or kernel density plot of the variable in each treated group and see that they overlap. The distributions don't have to be identical; that comes after matching or weighting. But there shouldn't be significant parts of the treated distribution that are outside the support of the control distribution.

There are many tools you can use to make such a plot, but the R package `cobalt` (of which I am the author) make it very easy using the `bal.plot()` function. See the [documentation page](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/reference/bal.plot.html) for examples.